# How to remove digits from string. based on the length and remove other letters with it

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

```
const item = "Dell Model 23506A Laptop M2";
const item2 = item.replace(/\d{2,}/g, "");
```

The above code will remove any words with "more than 2 digits found in a row, but will only remove the numbers from the Word.

Example the end result of the above will be `"Dell Model A Laptop M2"`, leaving the `A` from `23506A`.

How do you write the logic, that if more than 2 digits found in a row in a Word, to remove the entire word as a result.

Example the end result of the above should be `"Dell Model Laptop M2"`

Thus removing `23056A` entirely, because more than 2 digits we're found in a row (right after another).

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

`item.replace(/[^\s]*\d{2,}[^\s]*/g, "");`

You may also wish to get rid of the adjacent space:

`item.replace(/[^\s]*\d{2,}[^\s]*\s?/g, "");`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to remove all other strings that could possibly contain 2 digits like for example `1,50`, you can assert at least a char a-zA-Z

```
\b(?=\w*[A-Za-z])\w*\d{2}\w*\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?=\w*[A-Za-z])` Positive lookahead, assert a char a-zA-Z
- `\w*\d{2}\w*` Match 2 digits between optional word characters
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f8o6ul/1)